# Swift : Is it possible to add an empty stackview inside a scrollview?

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview, stackview

I have a fullscreen scrollview and inside a stackview that will be filled with elements at runtime. The problem is that I can't fix the missing constraints for the scrollview : Need constraints for Y position or height

Comment: Add some screenshot or more info plz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of the `scrollView`, is that it has "infinite" content size, so at the moment you are trying to add constraints inside it, he can't calculate them, my suggestion would be to add the `stackView` also programmatically as you do with the elements
you might want to use this function to anchor the stackView to its superview(`scrollView`)

```
func anchorSubview(_ view: UIView) {
    view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

This should be done after you `scrollView.addSubview(stackView)`

Comment: Thanks I will try that